# Understanding the code that creates a mutable.Map with mutable.MultiMap

Tags: scala, scala-collections

Can anyone explain what's going on in this dense code:

```
val m = new mutable.HashMap[Int, mutable.Set[String]] with mutable.MultiMap[Int, String]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As much as I know,

```
new mutable.HashMap[Int, mutable.Set[String]]
```

creates a mutable HashMap having key as Int and values as mutable Set of Strings

```
with mutable.MultiMap[Int, String]
```

This suggests that mutable.HashMap is enforced to mix-in mutable.MultiMap. 
The following can be the definition of HashMap

```
class HashMap {
   self: mutable.MultiMap => 
}
```

This is called as self annotation. It basically says that HashMap is not a multimap but its instances are promised to be so, therefore you can code HashMap as if it was a multimap